# Creating and using an SQL variable after some set text

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, bash

I'm needing to set some text into a field within a row, and use a SQL variable as part of that text. I'm then using this sql statement in a bash script.

I have

```
select UID from table1
1
```

I believe I created the variable correctly

```
set @simpleUID := UID from table1
```

I then need to use this variable as follows

```
update table2 set exp = 'http://standurl.co/@simpleUID'
```

However its not working and is giving me errors about an invalid command, and some errors about improper escaping.
Do I need to escape the variable when using it like this? I need that variable to be placed at the end of this URL that I'm placing into another field.

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause an error about escaping. You might get that if you used backslash instead of forward slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting the variable correctly. It should be:

```
SELECT UID FROM table1 INTO @simpleUID;
```

or

```
SET @simpleUID = (SELECT UID FROM table1);
```

To concatenate the variable to a string, use the `CONCAT()` function.

```
update table2 set exp = CONCAT('http://standurl.co/', @simpleUID);
```

You can also do it in one query without the variable:

```
UPDATE table2 SET exp = CONCAT('http://standurl.co/', (SELECT UID FROM table1));
```

Comment: I'm getting 'unrecognized command' when trying to create the variable in both ways you suggest. Could the ability to create variable be disabled in my database?
If that is the case, is there a way to insert that information with out using a variable?

Comment: I don't think so. You're using MySQL, right?

Comment: `UPDATE table2 SET exp = CONCAT('http://standurl.co/', (SELECT UID FROM table1))`

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! I'll keep digging into why variables are not able to be created, but this will get me around that for now.